# Handling Global Settings In Microservices

Tags: spring-boot, configuration, microservices

Supposed we had a couple of services `service-1`,`service-2`, `service-3`, we can handle global configurations like `DB configs`,`environment configs` etc using an externalized service like spring cloud config server or consul. But what is the best way to handle admin related settings in Micro-services e.g Max funding amount, vat, transaction limit etc setting that don't need a programmer to change ? ***note multiple services can use these values.***

Answer (score 1):

one way of doing this would be creating a bean which loads the data at the start of the app from db. In db you can have a table with admin privileges provide simple insert/update queries to the user who can/wants execute them. This user can be admin of the app who is using your app.

Other way would be creating your own properties/attributes and providing them in application.properties file. You can load those properties any of the beans which you think will need them.
eg (for spring boot):-

`spring.max.transaction.limit` -- in application.poperties

`@Value("${spring.max.transaction.limit}")
    private String transactionLimit;` -- in the bean